# How to access a global variable with a predicate containing a list

Tags: xquery

I'm not sure I phrased the title correctly, but let me try explaining:

Using [the first example from here](https://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/how-to-declare-global-variable-of-xquery-in-xml):

```
declare variable $message := ("message1","message2");
<output>
        <print>{$message[1]}</print>
        <print>{$message[2]}</print>
</output>
```

You get this output:

```
<output>    
  <print>message1</print>    
  <print>message2</print>    
</output>
```

I'm trying to get a similar effect using a more complex variable, [based on Question 5 here](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/XPath/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-querying_xml/seq-exercise-xml_countries_xpath_xquery_core/?child=first). The idea is to create a list of French-speaking and German-speaking countries, using this form:

```
<result>
  <French>
    <country>country-name</country>
            ...
  </French>
  <German>
    <country>country-name</country>
           ...
  </German>
</result>
```

There are various ways to do that, but I'm specifically interested in something along the lines of the first example, where I start with:

```
declare variable $lang := doc("countries.xml")//country/language[.=('French','German')];
```

and use a FLOWR expression that would look something like this:

```
<result>
<French>    
{for $f in (the first language specified in the $lang predicate)
return <country>{$f/data(@name)}</country>
}
</French>
<German>
{for $f in (the second language specified in the $lang predicate)
return <country>{$f/data(@name)}</country>
}
</German>
</result>
```

Is that doable and, if so, how?

Comment: It seems having `declare variable $languages as xs:string* := ('French', 'German');` and then processing `for $lang in $languages return element { $lang } { for $country in doc('countries.xml')//country[language = $lang] return <country>{$country/data(@name)}</country> }` is easier.

Comment: @MartinHonnen - Thanks, Martin - didn't think of this approach; it works with these minor changes: `<result>
{
for $lang in $languages 

return element { $lang }
{
for $country in doc('countries.xml')//country[language = $lang] 
return <country>{$country/data(@name)}</country> 

} } 

</result>`